# Using multer diskStorage with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, storage, multer

I'm translating a node.js server to typescript.

My funcion with node is:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const dir = './uploads/';
        mkdirp(dir, err => cb(err, dir));
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

router.post('/test', upload.fields({name: 'image'}), async function (req, res, next) {
...
});
```

But I have a lot of errors. For example I can't set the file argument as Express.File type, 'memoryStorage' does not accept arguments or mkdirp tells me that is not callable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's how I did it using the type definitions in the `@types/multer`.

If you haven't already, first install the type definitions for the multer package:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/multer
```

### Imports and `type` aliases

```
import { Request } from 'express'
import multer, { FileFilterCallback } from 'multer'

type DestinationCallback = (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void
type FileNameCallback = (error: Error | null, filename: string) => void
```

### For `storage`

```
export const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (
        request: Request,
        file: Express.Multer.File,
        callback: DestinationCallback
    ): void => {
        // ...Do your stuff here.
    },

    filename: (
        req: Request, 
        file: Express.Multer.File, 
        callback: FileNameCallback
    ): void => {
        // ...Do your stuff here.
    }
})
```

### For `fileFilter`

```
export const fileFilter = (
    request: Request,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    callback: FileFilterCallback
): void => {
    if (
        file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
    ) {
        callback(null, true)
    } else {
        callback(null, false)
    }
}
```

For cleaner code and separation of concerns, place the above two constants in a separate file like `config/multer.ts` or `util/multer.ts`

### Usage

Import and use the above constants in `app.ts` or `server.ts`:

```
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter })
```

Comment: `Express` is imported from `'express'`: `import type { Request, Express } from 'express'`

Answer (score 5):

I used the following code and it worked

```
   const guidGenerator = require('uuid/v1');

   // configurates how the files are gonna be stored
   const storage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function (req: Express.Request, file: Express.Multer.File, callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void) {
        callback(null, './upload/');
    },
    filename: function (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, callback: (error: Error | null, filename: string) => void) {
        const guid = guidGenerator();
        callback(null, guid + '_' + file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used this.

```js
const guidGenerator = require('uuid/v1');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, path.resolve('./upload/'))
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const guid = guidGenerator();
    callback(null, `${guid}-${file.originalname}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It works but I had to use any :S

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req: request, _file: any, cb: any) {
        const dir = './uploads/';
        mkdirp(dir, (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => {
            cb(err, dir)
        });
    },
    filename: function (_req: request, file: any, cb: any) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
```